# Imputing missing character values in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset called `credit_df` with dimensions 32561*15. It has a column for `native.country` with 1843 missing values. missing values are given as `?`

I have created a factor variable with the list of countries using the below code

```
country <- unique(credit_df$native.country)
```

The above code also came with one `?` value as it was part of the dataset. So i have removed that alone using the below

```
country <- as.data.frame(country)

country %>% filter(country != "?")
```

Now the `country` factor variable has all the country names in the dataset. Now I would like to assign those to the missing values in the column **randomly**. How do i do it ?

I tried the below code per one of the suggested methods

```
 credit_df$native.country[credit_df$native.country %in% c("?")] <-
      sample(country, NROW(credit_df$native.country[credit_df$native.country %in% c("?")]), replace = T)
```

but all the "?" turned out to be missing values

```
sum(is.na(credit_df$native.country))
[1] 583
```

**NOTE**: Even not considering this example if any of you could suggest how to impute character values randomly I am okay with it.

**Example** : if I have a column of country with missing values . and I have a vector/dataframe with a bunch of country names. How do i assign them randomly to the missing values in the country column

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `sample()`

```
credit_df$native.country[credit_df$native.country %in% c("?")] <-
  sample(country, NROW(credit_df$native.country[credit_df$native.country %in% c("?")]), replace = T)
```

The sample command here creates a vector using random values form `country`. The length of the generated vector is the same length as the number of rows you want to replace. The `replace = T` argument is only needed if you want to take a sample larger than the population (didn't know how much rows there are to replace and how many values there are in `country`).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was able to impute the values per your suggestion . I however got the below warning message

Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, credit_df$native.country %in% c("?"), value = c(40L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

I am proceeding further. I will get back if there is an issue.

Comment: Try to format the native.country column from factor to character before replacing the missing entries.

Comment: Nope.. it isn't solving the issue. All the countries are getting assigned to all the missing values...